# Why indexOf() still returns -1 when value exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fetching product codes from products.csv and pushing them into products array. When I search a string in the array it still returns -1 while it already has a matching value.

```
jQuery.get('v/wds-custom/products.csv', function(data) {
  var products = new Array();
  var rows = data.split("\n");
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
    products.push(rows[i].toLowerCase());
  if($('#vCSS_mainform').length > 0) {
    var mainform_action = $('#vCSS_mainform').attr('action').toLowerCase();
    if(mainform_action.indexOf("productdetails.asp") > -1) {
      var current_productCode = decodeURIComponent(mainform_action.split("=")[1]);
      console.log(products);  // ["alg-207", "alg-357", "alg-434"]
      console.log(current_productCode);  // alg-207
      console.log(products.indexOf(current_productCode)); // -1
    }
  }
});
```

**Important:** If I make products.csv single row just having alg-207 it returns 0 but is not working with multiple rows.

Comment: add console.log(rows[i]); and check to see if those values are what you expect.

Comment: ["alg-207", "alg-357", "alg-434"].indexOf("alg-207") returns 0, so there's an issue somewhere else. Can you paste the actual output of this script, as it appears in the console?

Comment: What is the value of `mainform_action`?

Comment: The console can be a bit tricky: If it's showing you `> Array[3]` for `products` and then you're clicking the arrow to see them, it may be showing you the contents of the array **as of when you click the arrow**, not when the line was logged. (Yes, really.) Chrome's works this way, and others may as well. This is one of the many reasons that `console.log` is not a substitute for setting a breakpoint and single-stepping through the code, examining variables while the execution is paused, in realtime.

Comment: Please provide the fiddle for it.

Comment: A fiddle or even better, a Stack Snippet, yeah. In any case, an [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah you seem correct. Looks like console.log is being tricky. Any good approach to handle this? This might be adding an extra white space at the start of each node. Because this happens from second line. Single line products.csv works fine.

Comment: @AZee: Using the debugger and single-stepping is the best approach. But if you **have** to use `console.log` for this, `console.log(JSON.stringify(...))` makes it log text, not live object references.

Comment: Put a debug break at the line with indexOf and see what the values are

Comment: As @SpencerWieczorek said, the only problem I have (ran a modified version) is with `mainform_action`, you aren't setting this to lowercase. IE gives index `0` back in the console. Otherwise go with T.J. and put `debugger` in your code just before the line with `decodeUriComponent`

Comment: @Mouser: `var mainform_action = $('#vCSS_mainform').attr('action').toLowerCase();` Note the call at the end.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you so much man!! You are such a life saver!! That was actually /r with each node value

Comment: @AZee: Cool, I'm glad that helped! Indirectly, as it turned out, but still... :-)

Comment: Ah, invisible chars would've been the next guess :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're seeing an artifact of the console. The console can be a bit tricky: If it's showing you `> Array[3]` for products and then you're clicking the arrow to see them, it may be showing you the contents of the array **as of when you click the arrow**, not when the line was logged. (Yes, really.) Chrome's works this way (sometimes, it varies depending on whether the console is closed or open when `log` is called — yes, really), and others may as well. This is one of the many reasons that console.log is not a substitute for setting a breakpoint and single-stepping through the code, examining variables while the execution is paused, in realtime.

But if for some reason you **have** to use `console.log` instead of the debugger, you can make it log text rather than live object references by doing:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(products));
```

...and similar instead.

Comment: Thank you!! There was actually "/r" with each node value of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your **important**, and assuming that `data` is a string of CSV, it could be that you are missing a step in the CSV parsing.  The algorithm splits on `"\n"`, but never splits on commas.  So for many rows of CSV with multiple entries, like

```
alg-207,alg-208
alg-203,alg-105
```

You might be getting a products array that looks like:

```
["alg-207,alg-208","alg-203,alg-105"]
```

That would explain why it works when there's a single-element row with the item you search for, but not with multiple elements.

If this is the case, you would need to add logic to split each row on commas, to get an array of arrays to process.

If it's not the case that you have rows with multiple elements, I'm not as sure what could be going on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not the case.